# WSO2 API Manager Scopes for Federated Users

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have WSO2 API Manager federated setup with `Azure AD`. I can use the `implicit` and `code` grant type to generate the access tokens.

Now I want to use the WSO2 API Manager `scope` functionality to `limit the access` on certain API `resources`. I have created the `role` in API manager and added the `scope` on `API publisher` for the API resource. But when I generate the access token using `scope` value, it doesn't return the token with correct `scope`. But if I assign the `local user` to that role and generate the access token it works fine.

I wonder if WSO2 API manager support `scope` management for `Federated` users.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured your key manager user store as secondary user store of APIM?

Comment: No, any specific reason to configure secondary user store?

Comment: Yes, AKAIU, you mean by federated user is the user you have created in your key manager. In order to register this user into APIM you need to configure user store of key manager as secondary user store of APIM. At the moment, haven't you configured any user store in APIM

Comment: Or else can you explain what do you mean exactly by federated user

Answer (score 2):

By defaut roles are checked against the userstore managers, therefore if federated users are not findable in a local userstore manager, it is difficult to assign roles to them.

You have several options:

- if you are using SAML, you can specify `-DcheckRolesFromSamlAssertion=true` it was quite tricky to find this one
- create a secondary local (e. g. jdbc) userstore and setup the outbound provisioning for federated users. This way all federated users and their roles will be mirrored in a local userstore and their roles will be findable by the scope provider